# Как перенаправить динамический субдомен в подпапку с именем этого субдомена?

Tags: firebase, redirect, dns, hosting

На домене test.com есть динамические субдомены пользователей вида username.test.com.

Как сделать перенаправление username.test.com в test.com/u/username?

Задача усложняется тем, что хостинг - **firebase**!

Comment: ответ целиком и полностью зависит от используемой реализации http-сервера. вы её не указали, потому вопрос следует закрыть как слишком общий (иначе следовало бы закрыть как дубликат подходящего вопроса (про настройку конкретной реализации http-сервера) — ведь подобные вопросы задаются регулярно).

Comment: Указал. Реализация - firebase.

Comment: Так же, как минимум, возможен вариант без http-сервера. Например с помощью Cloudflare rules - [Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427) (Вариант мне не подходит из за неадекватной цены на одну эту услугу).